# Python to EXE builds a nothing-doing file

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

I used [cx_Freeze](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cx_Freeze) module to convert my Python applications to Windows.

I have a simple Python file `norm.py` :

```
print("Hi there !")
```

Another file `makeup.py` to convert the above into exe:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

include_files = ['autorun.inf']
os_base = None

if sys.platform == "win32":
    os_base = "Win32GUI"

setup(name="puzzle",
        version="0.1",
        description="Very cool puzzle",
        options={'build_exe':{'include_files':include_files}},
        executables=[Executable("norm.py", base=os_base)])
```

I also have `autorun.inf` in the same folder.
There are also no errors coming when I build this by running command:

```
python makeup.py build
```

It creates a `build` folder inside which there is `norm.exe` .When I run this exe through my terminal , it doesn't do anything.I am expecting it to print `"Hi there!"`

I am using Python 3.4 as some posts said that 3.5 has a problem with this module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a GUI application using

```
if sys.platform == "win32":
    os_base = "Win32GUI"
```

You should remove this, in order to build a console application.

Comment: Then what should I set the value of OS_base to?

Comment: @TilakMadichetti : it should be None, the Win32GUI base hide the console.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't have any errors, is probably that you have to write "input()" below of "print("Hi there !")".

```
print ("Hi there !")
input()
```

Comment: Please consider explaining the solution; why would it work.